# retrieve firebase database json

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

l am trying to retrieve all data in a firebase database . When l used this code    `<h1>{{ item | async | json }}</h1>` depending on doc of angularfire2 object l got list of json response object in html

```
{
  "type": "value",
  "payload": {
    "8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2": {
      "-LWl294Hs6YjkvJE5pqi": {
        "name": "ddd",
        "title": "dd"
      },
      "-LWlEonKLWfOttzirqp7": {
        "name": "sas",
        "title": "ass"
      },
      "-LWlGvn81Kes2A-1UcC2": {
        "name": "asa",
        "title": "asass"
      },
      "-LWlK92A7gaRkKVrZSFU": {
        "name": "ddd",
        "title": "ddd"
      },
      "-LWla1PYxsIFKhaCXvtu": {
        "name": "ff",
        "title": "fdsf"
      },
      "-LWpfRJP8VdwG927wyXS": {
        "name": "ali",
        "title": "ali"
      },
      "-LWph3ei12KTNyirdnZb": {
        "name": "ddddd",
        "title": "daD"
      }
    },
    "WUM2HBkGo8TFDeOjEqO1s3lCj1p1": {
      "-LWlHlhyS9m3ECS3wIdk": {
        "name": "qwqsasasa",
        "title": "as"
      },
      "-LWlHmXZAJdSPZurO7ii": {
        "name": "qwqsasasa",
        "title": "as"
      },
      "-LWph-fv4JMtTk22aE5X": {
        "name": "sssssssssssssssssssssssss",
        "title": "sssssssssssssssssssssssss"
      }
    }
  },
  "key": "report"
}
```

l want to get from this list json object only `title` and `name` . l used this code but l got empty page in html no data to show !

```
  <h1>{{ (item | async)?.name }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ (item | async)?.title }}</h1>
```

main code

```
  itemRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  item: Observable<any>;

      ionViewWillLoad(){
        this.fire.authState.subscribe(data => {
          if(data && data.email && data.uid){
            this.toastCtrl.create({
              message : ` welcome ${data.email}`,
              duration:2000
            }).present()

            this.itemRef = this.db.object('report');
            this.item = this.itemRef.snapshotChanges();

          }

        })

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/report` key in your database seems to hold a list of objects: specifically a list of reports for each user, so with two nested keys under `/report`. But your code is loading it as a single object. This leads to this HTML `<h1>{{ (item | async)?.name }}</h1>` essentially displaying `/report/name`, which doesn't exist in your database.

If you want to **display the name and title of a single report**, you need to know the keys of that report. For example to show the first report for the first user:

```
this.itemRef = this.db.object('report/8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2/-LWl294Hs6YjkvJE5pqi');
```

The first subkey `8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2` here is the UID of the user whose report you're showing and the `-LWl294Hs6YjkvJE5pqi` is the first report of that user.

If you want to **display all reports for a user**, you will need to again know the key of the user and pass it into the database. But since you then get back a list of reports, you'll also need to use the `list` service from AngularFire and loop over the results in your HTML template, so that it generates the elements for each report:

```
this.reports = this.db.list('report/8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2');
```

And:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let report of reports | async">
     {{ item.title }} - {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to **display a nested list of all reports for all users**, you'd start with the same as just above, but now load the data for all users, and use another `ngFor` to loop over the users first.

Also see:

- the [AngularFire documentation on lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md)
- this [tutorial on building a CRUD application with AngularFire](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/reactive-crud-app-with-angular-and-firebase-tutorial/)

Comment: l want  to display all reports for a users because my app content blog

Comment: I just added a description of what to do for that too. I **highly** recommend that you spend some time on the tutorials and documentation first, since your approach is quite far off.

Comment: right now , l spent 10 days about this problem and all tries is failed